# How to use Java string replaceAll to replace all occurrences of " in a string to \"

Tags: java, string

Suppose a Java string, str contains '**double" quote"test**' in which there are 2 double quotes.  I want to write a Java program to replace all occurrences of double quote " inside str by \" (i.e. precedes every double quote with a backslash).

I tried the following code but failed, it may relate to specific feature of double quote, backslash.

str.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");

Please advise how to achieve this.   Thank you

Comment: replaceAll is regexp-based. Use replace instead: ``str.replace("\"", "\\\"");``

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
String str = "hello\" world";
System.out.println(str.replace("\"", "\\\\\""));
```

**output**

```
hello\\" world
```